# Can iTunes for Windows play 4K movies that purchased from iTunes Store?

Tags: itunes, appletv, itunes-store, streaming

I rented a 4K movie from iTunes Store in iTunes for Windows. But the resolution seemed not to be 4K when it started playing. (My monitor is 2K)

I checked the preferences of iTunes and found something strange. There doesn't seem to be any 4K options.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you cannot play 4K with iTunes for Windows. According to [Apple.com](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207949), 4K content requires macOS, iOS, or tvOS.

---

Additionally, note that even on supported platforms, 4K content cannot be downloaded. It can only be streamed. If a movie is downloaded before playing it (or if it's playing off an in-progress download), it will never be higher than 1080p, regardless of the platform.